# How to update to new SQL database username and password?

Tags: wordpress, sql

We recently received a site dump from the previous host, inclusive of the Civi CRM SQL database.  When creating a new account, I had to create a new database Username and Password.  Does this need to be added/updated anywhere with the Civi CRM plugin (WordPress) in order to connect properly?  Would like to be sure before repointing the domain.

Thanks,

Steven

Answer (score 1):

These values need to be entered in the civicrm.settings.php file (i assume this is the same for WP as for Drupal)